# ClosedXML Adding Formula creates unreadable content

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio, closedxml

I am adding a formula to worksheet using C# closedxml but it is coming back as unreadable content.  I think the reason is the slashed that I added to the formula but I need the slashes to escape the quotes because I need the quotes in the formula.  How else can I do this?

Here is my code:

```
CodeWorksheet.Range(CodeWorksheet.Cell(2, 25).Address, CodeWorksheet.Cell(CodeWorksheet.LastRowUsed().RowNumber(), 25).Address).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(SUM(RC[-6]:RC[-1])>0,\" + \",\")";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you only have one double quote in the "if false" part of your formula.  Try changing

```
=IF(SUM(RC[-6]:RC[-1])>0,\" + \",\")
```

to

```
=IF(SUM(RC[-6]:RC[-1])>0,\" + \",\"\")
```